# Push Notification send and receive in iOS?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I want to develop an app regarding push notification.

I want to send a push notification to 5 persons who has installed my app and are stored in my directory.

1. Can I send Push Notification to 5 people using their UDID which I received from each and every person who has installed App. (As UDID is banned)
2. I want to send them continuously to 5 persons till one does not press OK button on Alert?
3. Which service should I use for Push Notification?
4. Is push notification receives on time or it delays?

Comment: You really should read the notification documentation provided by Apple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant send the push notification using UDID, you can use the Apple service for sending the push notifications via device-token and pem file which is explained in below link.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Any push notification that isn't delivered immediately was queued for future redelivery because your device was not connected to the service. "Immediately" of course needs to take latency for your connection into account. Outlying cases would be beyond 60 seconds as APNs will time out at that point.

Still you have any query then you can refer the below link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html

Comment: what should we use, as UDID is banned by apple now?

Comment: to identify the unique device you can use the following code
https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5

Comment: @Duaan: then wats the solution?

Comment: i think there is no solution for ios5 or below, have a look at the link http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/04/unique-identifiers/   ( scroll down and see the Decisions Section )